# World of Warcraft Emulator C++ Scheduled event every X minutes

Tags: c++, emulation, world-of-warcraft

Some of us might know about `World of Warcraft and emulators`.

1. I am currently using the emulator ArcEmu (http://arcemu.org/)
2. I want to create a scheduled event every X minutes to check a player's information
3. and fill in a database table with that information (Each character will have a table record and I want to update it on each event run).
4. The problem here is that my C++ knowledge is too low for me to do such an event.
5. I tried searching for possible examples of the exact same script, but I couldn't find anything. Just in case somebody is asking me why can't I do it from the website with the current tables I will post my whole idea here.
6. I would like to modify the character module for the best **World of Warcraft Contents Management System** out there - **FusionCMS** to show a lot more information than it does right now.
7. I want to do it as accurate as possible. I would also like to get information on the progress made on the ranking and on gearing. I cannot provide any code examples here.
8. Here is a link to the **ArcEmu's repository in GitHub** - `http://github.com/ArcEmu/ArcEmu`.
9. My question is... what are the possible ways for me to create a scheduled event on this emulator?

Comment: We can't write code for you, you'll have to either hire a programmer or do the study/implementing by yourself. Sorry

Comment: I'm not asking for someone to write code for me, I'm asking for possible ways to create a sheduled event in the emulator. I should update the question...

Comment: This can be achieved using AzerothCore (https://github.com/azerothcore), however the question is too broad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way is to do this with the included EventMgr. Try `sEventMgr.AddEvent()`.